# Firefox: Paste file path in file dialog box

Tags: firefox, dialog

When saving a file it is possible to paste the file name. But I have found no obvious way to paste the path while keeping the file name: You have to click, scroll, click your way through the file system.

A similar problem occurs in the select file dialog, when you upload a file. Again you cannot simply <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> the path to the file.

Firefox does not have this limitation in the location bar: Here you are free to paste or edit the URL, and that is useful if you are browsing https://foo/bar/baz/quux, but know you need to go to https://foo/fob/baz/quux, so it seems a bit weird to limit this when dealing with files on the local machine.

In file selection dialog: Is it possible to make Firefox show the path as a text string that you can edit (e.g. paste into)?

Firefox: 75.0 (on Ubuntu 18.04).